# Mixed ANOVA (lme) returns error for alphabetic variable

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I have a large data set with persons who answered questionnaires at several measurement points. I want to run an ANOVA using the `lme` function with my `"SERIAL"` variable as identifying the persons (which is the serial code of a person in letters and numbers, e.g. YVEDPEPGV9). So person YVEDPEPGV9 answers the RRS and PSWQ questionnaires at two times (see below).

Unfortunately R returns an error and tells me that operations are only possible for numeric, logical and complex types. Do I need to recode the SERIAL variable into a variable which assigns only numbers to every person? Or is there a way that R accepts the variable as assigning variable? If I have to create a new variable, which would be the smartest way to assign an identifying number to every person (to every Serial Code)?

This is my code for the ANOVA so far:

```
anova_lme <-lme(data=ds, fixed=ABB~group * RRS * PSWQ,  
                         random=1|"SERIAL", na.action=na.omit)
```

between = group

within = RRS and PSWQ

Comment: i think the notation may be `random=~1 |SERIAL` (with a tilde, and no quotes)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!